# Run error 500 by php

Tags: php, html, server

I'm trying to specific way to send data to my root server
So I made a form:

```
    <form action="upload.php" id="s2" style="display: block;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
    <p><input style="margin:0px" onchange="document.getElementById('adm11').disabled = !this.checked;document.getElementById('adm12').disabled = !this.checked;" class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="option1">
    <label class="w3-validate">Admin</label><input id="adm11" style="margin:0 0 0 20px;" class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="option2" disabled="">
    <label class="w3-validate">OverWrite</label></p>
    <p>
    <button class="w3-btn w3-blue">Submit</button><input id="adm12" class="w3-input" name="pass1" type="password" style="display:inline-block;width:60%;margin-left:15px;" disabled=""></p>
    </form>
```

with an admin button that will send a password and specific checkbox to **PHP** server
My Problem is I can not find a way to comparing the password
every time I try I got this error

example.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

I'm Beginner in PHP servers.
I don't have **SQL server**, so I got way by make file and make it private by **.htaccess**

This is the Last test for the PHP code:

```
$myfile = fopen("pass3.ini", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $pass2 = fread($myfile,filesize("pass3.ini"));
    fclose($myfile);
    echo $pass2
    if ($pass2 = $_POST["pass1"]) {echo "yes"};
```

Has anyone any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from where you missed the closing semi-colon in `echo $pass2`, there are a few more errors, where you're doing an assignment here with a single equal sign (for one thing):

```
if ($pass2 = $_POST["pass1"])
```

rather than doing a comparison using two:

```
if ($pass2 == $_POST["pass1"])
```

The semi-colon in this is also misplaced:

```
if ($pass2 = $_POST["pass1"]) {echo "yes"};
                                          ^ right there
```

where it should read as

```
if ($pass2 == $_POST["pass1"]) { echo "yes"; }
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Using error reporting, would have thrown you a parse error:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

But, would not have thrown an error about the present assignment, since (believe it or not) is a valid statement.

Also check for proper permissions on the file you're trying to read from and that the path for it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `;` after `echo $pass2`

Comment: Sure, but you missed something.

Comment: @fred-ii missed something special

Answer (score 0):

Replace your HTML following line:

```
<button class="w3-btn w3-blue">Submit</button><input id="adm12" class="w3-input" name="pass1" type="password" style="display:inline-block;width:60%;margin-left:15px;" disabled=""></p>
    </form>
```

With:

```
<input id="adm12" class="w3-input" name="pass1" type="password" style="display:inline-block;width:60%;margin-left:15px;" value="something" disabled/>
<input type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-blue" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

You need to give some value in id="adm12" so that you can compare it later :) I made "something" as an example.

Anyways also update you php file:

```
$myfile = fopen("pass3.ini", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $pass2 = fread($myfile,filesize("pass3.ini"));
    fclose($myfile);
    echo $pass2;
    echo $_POST["pass1"]; //it will paste "something"
    if ($pass2 === $_POST["pass1"]) {echo "yes"};//idk whats in your $pass2 but if its something same you are sending from html then it will print "yes"
```